# How to filter tag values in template variable of Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-templating

all.
I'm new to Grafana and I want to get only tag values what I want.
For example,

[image]

As you can see,"23" is a value of tags, I just want to get template variable by "23".

[image]

But now I get so many template variables so that every time I have to seek it for long time.

I'd like to get some tags like "23" rather than seek it from all tags.
Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: So you only want 23 to show as a value in the template variable ?

Comment: Yep, and the question has been done, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use "IN" when filtering TAGs youll need to do something like this (i.e only show 23 and 24)

Your query should be
`SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY "measurementPoint" where ("measurementPoint" = '23') or ("measurementPoint" = '24')`

Ofcourse if you know its only going to be 23 or something else you could just use static variables or have i misunderstood your question ?

Comment: okay, thanks a lot. and I should have known it because it's influxdb syntax. I thought it maybe Grafana syntax. To be honest, I have another question..maybe I should raise it in another Question...

Comment: Please mark this as a correct answer if it has worked. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again. This is my first time to ask questions so no more experience.